# Overriding functions for different data types

Tags: haskell, overriding

Im trying to define a function which I want to behave slightly differently depending on what datatype is passed in as the argument, strings and integers. How would one go about doing this? Or are there any changes you could suggest to somehow compose these two into one function. Ive read that trying to validate the datatype is not very haskell like so I thought overriding might be the way to go to do this but the compiler doesnt like the duplicate :(

```
jumpTo :: Int -> [String] -> [String]
jumpTo index t = do 
    let (x,y) = splitAt index t
    init x ++ [last x ++ "QQ"] ++ y

jumpTo :: String -> [String] -> [String]
jumpTo string t = do 
    pos <- [fromJust (findWord string t)]
    let (x,y) = splitAt pos a
    init x ++ [last x ++ "QQ"] ++ y
```

In words, I want a function `jumpTo` which can either be passed a `String` or `Int` as its first argument; if its a string, I find it in the list, and for an integer I do the operations with the index straight away. It just seems more elegant to have the same function doing this.

Comment: That's the idea behind *typeclasses*: http://learnyouahaskell.com/types-and-typeclasses it is used for "ad-hoc polymorphism".

Comment: as far as I understand this article, typeclasses allow you to work with different datatypes in the same function, but not actually override the function definition itself?

Comment: well you define your `jumpTo` in a typeclass `class JumpTo a` as `jumpTo :: a -> [String] -> [String]`, and then you declare two instances: `instance JumpTo Int`, and `instance JumpTo String`. For each `instance` you can provide a different implementation. In fact that is how `show` works for example: every type defines its specific way of `show`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is exactly the idea behind type classes: you define your function (or a group of functions) not by itself, but as belonging to a type class, which is tagged with a type variable (or several). Then you define one or more instances of the type class with different types substituted for that type variable, and you define separate bodies for the function in each instance. The end effect is that the function has different body depending on the types of its arguments or result.

In your example:

```
class JumpTo a where
    jumpTo :: a -> [String] -> [String]

instance JumpTo Int where
    jumpTo index t = do 
        let (x,y) = splitAt index t
        init x ++ [last x ++ "QQ"] ++ y

instance JumpTo String where
    jumpTo string t = do 
        pos <- [fromJust (findWord string t)]
        let (x,y) = splitAt pos a
        init x ++ [last x ++ "QQ"] ++ y
```

Comment: thank you, this makes sense now! On compile I'm getting illegal instance declaration for the String instance, rewriting it to [] Char doesnt help either. I've tried "promising" haskell that I wont define any overlapping instances, however by using the functions I get errors thrown at me saying that its too ambigious. :[ how does one go about using String then?

Comment: @peterxz You will need to turn on `TypeSynonymInstances` and `FlexibleInstances`. Your code as written still won't compile after you've done this, but that's an unrelated problem.